# Special orthogonal groups over spheres

Tags: gn.general-topology, manifolds, fibre-bundles

In Norman Steenrod's book "The Topology of Fibre Bundles", on page 37, one can find the following conjecture: if $n$ is a power of two then the fibre bundle with the projection $SO(n)\to SO(n)/SO(n-1)=\mathbb S^{n-1}$ is equivalent to the product bundle. Is this conjecture true?

Comment: Famously, the answer is 'no'.  It is now known that this bundle is trivial if and only if $n=1,2,4,8$.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please provide a reference?

Comment: There are two papers by J. F. Adams in 1962, both titled "Vector fields on spheres", and they contain the proof of the above statement.  They are: "Vector fields on spheres". Topology 1 (1962) 63–65 and "Vector fields on spheres"  Ann. of Math. (2) 75 (1962) 603–632.  I believe that the latter contains the full details and, in fact, proves much more, determining the maximum number of linearly independent vector fields on the $n$-sphere for all $n$.  The former doesn't give quite as complete a solution, but it does contain enough to solve the parallelizability problem on spheres.